# uploading a jar file to software center

Tags: package-management, java, deb, upload, jar

i am new here.. 
i am a Java programmer how can i upload a .jar file to ubuntu software center?
i created an account in ubuntu Apps and i building a .deb from my .jar file but i do not know yet how to upload it any idea guys?

thanx in advance

Comment: Maybe this works for you https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Personal

Comment: should i upload .deb file or should i build an other format?